# pandas group by confusion -- unhashable type

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Using Pandas data frame group by feature and I want to group by column `c_b` and calculate unique count for column `c_a` and column `c_c`. My expected results are,

**Expected results**,

```
c_b,c_a_unique_count,c_c_unique_count
python,2,2
c++,2,2
```

Met with strange error about `unhashable type`, does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

**Input file**,

```
c_a,c_b,c_c,c_d
hello,python,numpy,0.0
hi,python,pandas,1.0
ho,c++,vector,0.0
ho,c++,std,1.0
go,c++,std,0.0
```

**Source code**,

```
sample = pd.read_csv('123.csv', header=None, skiprows=1,
    dtype={0:str, 1:str, 2:str, 3:float})
sample.columns = pd.Index(data=['c_a', 'c_b', 'c_c', 'c_d'])
sample['c_d'] = sample['c_d'].astype('int64')
sampleGroup = sample.groupby('c_b')
results = sampleGroup.count()[:,[0,2]]
results.to_csv(derivedFeatureFile, index= False)
```

**Error message**,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/personal/featureExtraction/kaggleExercise.py", line 134, in <module>
    unitTest()
  File "/Users/foo/personal/featureExtraction/kaggleExercise.py", line 129, in unitTest
    results = sampleGroup.count()[:,[0,2]]
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Users/foo/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1348, in _get_item_cache
    res = cache.get(item)
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: `sampleGroup.count()[:,[0,2]]` what are you trying to do here? Try changing it to `sampleGroup.count().iloc[:,[0,2]]` if you want to get the first and the third column (you can do that on the groupby object too). (`df.groupby('a')[[0, 2]].count()`)

Comment: Thanks @ayhan, your method works, but it seems results only have column `c_a` and `c_d`, maybe I thought is wrong -- I think `c_b` is automatically included since it is the column which group by is on,
`c_a,c_d
3,3
2,2`

Comment: Yes grouping column becomes the index. You can access those columns by label too. What is the expected output?

Comment: @ayhan, I post my expected results on the beginning part of the post, and I expect to output the group column value itself (in my example, it is value of column `c_b`, and unique count for column `c_a` and `c_c`). If you have any solutions, it will be great.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I posted an answer, with an without taking `c_b` as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number of unique elements in each group, you can use:

```
df.groupby('c_b')['c_a', 'c_d'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
```

---

```
df.groupby('c_b')['c_a', 'c_d'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
Out: 
        c_a  c_d
c_b             
c++       2    2
python    2    2

df.groupby('c_b', as_index=False)['c_a', 'c_d'].agg(pd.Series.nunique)
Out: 
      c_b  c_a  c_d
0     c++    2    2
1  python    2    2
```

Comment: Thanks ayhan, the differences between the last two example is whether there is an additional integer incremental column?

Comment: Thanks ayhan for the help, mark your reply as answer.

Comment: That's the index of the dataframe. In the first one, the index is `c_b`.

Comment: Thanks ayhan, so in your first example, (1) `c_b` is not a column, it is an index, and in the 2nd example, `c_b` is a column, not an index -- and an integer column makes the index, correct? (2) Why there must be an index?

Comment: That's correct. Index is a way to differentiate rows and makes accessing easier/faster.

Comment: Thanks ayhan for the patience to explain to me, have a good weekend. :)